# Automatic mount /dev/sda1 under schroot

Tags: mount, udev, schroot

I have access to a Ubuntu system which is like this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   650M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 372.5G  0 part /
```

I have setup a Debian/sid schroot like this:

```
$ cat /etc/schroot/chroot.d/sid64 
[sid64]
description=Contains the SPICE program
aliases=sid
type=directory
directory=/home/malat/schroots/sid-root
users=malat
root-groups=root
profile=desktop
personality=linux
preserve-environment=true
```

I have not changed anything to `/etc/schroot/default/fstab`, and when going inside my schroot `sid64` here is what I see:

```
$ schroot -c sid
(sid64)$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   650M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 372.5G  0 part /var/lib/dbus
```

If I manually do:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/bdc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   650M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 372.5G  0 part /var/lib/dbus
```

How can I automatically mount `/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231` under my schroot (this is my main disk where my data is located) ?

---

So far I tried a naive:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/malat/schroots/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
$ tail -1 /etc/schroot/default/fstab 
/dev/disk/by-uuid/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none rw,bind 0 0
$ schroot -c sid
(sid64)$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  8 01:00 /dev/disk/by-uuid/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 -> ../../sda1
```

as well as:

```
$ tail -1 /etc/schroot/default/fstab
/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none    rw,bind 0 0
```

Both did not work for me.

---

I also tried a naive:

```
$ sudo mount --rbind /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /home/malat/schroots/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
$ mount | grep dbc64c37
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
/dev/sda1 on /home/malat/schroots/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
$ schroot -c sid
(sid64)$ ls -al /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
-> empty !
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem, but if this is what you want?
`mount /dev/sda1 /home/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231`
(with root from your normal environment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the solution was simply to read properly my schroot config file. It stated:

```
$ cat /etc/schroot/chroot.d/sid64 
[...]
profile=desktop
```

So I need to edit the file: `/etc/schroot/desktop/fstab` and not `/etc/schroot/default/fstab` (**desktop** != **default**).

I used :

```
$ tail -1 /etc/schroot/desktop/fstab 
/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none    rw,bind 0 0
```

And now I have:

```
$ schroot -c sid
(sid64)$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   650M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 372.5G  0 part /var/lib/dbus
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to correct your bind mount syntax after my post to get it working and post it as elaborate own answer in a bounty question. Hopefully you will get all the deserved attention in next questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Your root fs is on the pt      : "nvme0n1p2"
2. The device `sda1` is mounted on: "/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231"
3. Your chroot is created under   : "/home/malat/debian/sid-root/"
4. The schroot mnt-pnt shall be   : "/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231" (in chroot)
```

Your first mistake on your first try:

You tried to auto-mount the partition `sda1`, instead of giving the mount-point of the already mounted filesystem:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none rw,bind 0
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none rw,bind 0 0
```

Partitions are never mounted via bind, already mounted directories or even files are. The correct configuration for the `/etc/fstab` within your chroot would look like this:

```
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

**You do NOT do that** - unless you unmounted `sda1` outside of the chroot! You effectively would double mount `sda1` **TWICE** and corrupt the fs therefore, if possible after all.

Your second try outside of the chroot should have worked:

```
sudo mount --rbind /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231
```

But the output of `mount` doesn't fit:

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

The first output of `lsblk` told us, that there is no partition for the `home` tree! So why does mount state the `bind` mountpoint to be on `/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231`? The correct path should be `/home/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231` on `nvme0n1p2`!

Try:

```
Don't chroot, yet!
Try bind mounting with full paths:
sudo mount --rbind "/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231" "/home/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231"
```

If it is a success, you can automate this without `schroot`outside of your chroot in the `fstab` with:

```
/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 /home/malat/debian/sid-root/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231 none bind 0 0
```

Since a chroot prevents access to the "host" file-hierarchy and you mentioned to not having altered `/etc/schroot/default/fstab`, the `bind mount` **within** the schroot should fail. That is because `/mnt` is not included in the schroot fstab. And if it was, it would already have been "bind mounted".

This question provoked me and took me 2hrs to answer. I Hope it works. Btw, i have been remembered about schroot and got me a basic understanding about the mounting, now. ;)

PS
The output of `lsblk` within the chroot can't be correct! It states that `sda1` mounted outside of the chroot under `/mnt/dbc64c37-340a-49e5-8184-a69e01e5e231` would be the root (/) within the chroot. This is false! The root of the chroot is `/home/malat/debian/sid-root/`on the partition `nvme0n1p2`!